# IPv6 HTTP issue

Tags: http, routes, ipv6

I have configured a home server, which deals with my ADSL connexion and is used as a router by other computers. It has an IPv6 connexion that works very well.

I want the other computers to have access to internet via IPv6 too, but, strangely, some IPv6 websites can't be used (ex: mozilla.org, facebook.com...) whereas some other works very well (ex: google.com, www.myipv6.org...). The problem seems to be with HTTP only : I can ping every IPv6 server.

IPv6 configuration on the PC :

```
ip -6 address add 2001:41d0:xxxx:2240::20/64 dev eth2
ip -6 route add default via 2001:41d0:xxxx:2240:: dev eth2
```

Ping Test (everything is ok) :

```
# ping6 -q -c 10 google.com
PING google.com(par03s02-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes

--- google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.721/41.686/127.902/28.938 ms

# ping6 -q -c 10 mozilla.org
PING mozilla.org(2620:101:8008:5::2:1) 56 data bytes

--- mozilla.org ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 194.732/198.983/230.808/10.616 ms
```

IPv6 HTTP access to google.com -> Ok (with firefox too) :

```
# wget -6 google.com
--2013-02-02 14:25:51--  http://google.com/
Résolution de google.com (google.com)... 2a00:1450:4007:803::100e
Connexion vers google.com (google.com)|2a00:1450:4007:803::100e|:80... connecté.
< HTTP redirections >
2013-02-02 14:25:52 (1,40 MB/s) - «index.html.2» sauvegardé [10584]
```

IPv6 HTTP access to mozilla.org -> Doesn't work (with firefox too) :

```
# wget -6 mozilla.org
--2013-02-02 14:30:22--  http://mozilla.org/
Résolution de mozilla.org (mozilla.org)... 2620:101:8008:5::2:1
Connexion vers mozilla.org (mozilla.org)|2620:101:8008:5::2:1|:80... connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse... 301 Moved Permanently
Emplacement: http://www.mozilla.org/ [suivant]
--2013-02-02 14:30:22--  http://www.mozilla.org/
Résolution de www.mozilla.org (www.mozilla.org)... 2620:101:8008:5::2:1
Réutilisation de la connexion existante vers mozilla.org:80.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse... 301 Moved Permanently
Emplacement: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/ [suivant]
--2013-02-02 14:30:22--  http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/
Réutilisation de la connexion existante vers mozilla.org:80.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse... 
< Won't go any further >
```

.. Whereas IPv4 will work :

```
wget -4 mozilla.org
< Ok >
```

On my router, I have no problem to access mozilla.org and facebook.com via IPv6.

Moreover, my computer is completly accessible from outside via IPv6 :

```
< On an IPv6 server, out of my local network >
wget -6 http://[2001:41d0:xxxx:2240::20]
< Ok >
```

Comment: This must be www.mozilla.org issue. It responds with `301 Moved Permanently` - it means www.mozilla.org does not want to repond on this ipv6 address, and sends you elsewhere.

Comment: This problem also occures with other websites like facebook.com. Moreover, my router, in the same IPv6 network, can access these sites, so it can't be some sort of "IPv6 network blacklist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really smells like a Path MTU Discovery (PMTUd) issue. ping uses by
default small packets: they are always smaller than the MTU and
therefore go fine. HTTP uses small packets for requests (do note wget
can connect and send the request) but responses
are typically the size of the MTU. If you go through a tunnel
(something common with IPv6) *and* some router on the path stupidely
blocks the ICP Packet Too Big messages, you get what you saw.

To test big packets with ping, use the -s option, for instance `ping6 -q -c 10 -s 1490 mozilla.org`.

There is no easy solution, except trying to find out the offending
routers (which can be far away from you) and convince their
administrators to fix them.

Otherwise, there are local hacks, for example to decrease the TCP Maximum Segment Size (MSS), but they strongly depend on your operating system.

Comment: You were right. My ethernet MTU was 1500, I changed it to 1492 and now everything works fine. I changed the MTU on my router (in /etc/network/interfaces) and I added "AdvLinkMTU 1492;" to my radvd.conf on my router. Is it the best way to solve that problem ?